# JComponent showing full size or not showing at all

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jcomponent

I have the following code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ModuleGui extends JComponent {

protected ShapeResizeHandler shapeResizeHandler = new ShapeResizeHandler();
public ModuleGui(){ 
    this.addMouseListener(shapeResizeHandler);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(shapeResizeHandler);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension (400, 400);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}

private class ShapeResizeHandler extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println(e.getPoint().getX() + " " + e.getPoint().getY());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(){
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    }
}
}
```

Used in the following class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui {
private JFrame mainFrame = null;

public Gui(){
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setTitle("--");
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    ModuleGui moduleGui = new ModuleGui();
    moduleGui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    JPanel aux = new JPanel();
    aux.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    aux.add(moduleGui);

    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(aux);    
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Now I don't really understand why the `JComponent` either shows on the whole screen if I keep the `BorderLayout` for the `JPanel` or doesn't show at all if I remove it.

Comment: It has something to do with `mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` but as of this moment, I've not figured the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the following line:

```
g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Imagine that your display is 1600x900, if you don't set the BorderLayout, it means that you use the FlowLayout (with alignement CENTERED). Preferred size is 400x400 (because of your override, btw, calling setPreferredSize is useless here), so it means that FlowLayout will position your component around the point (600, 5). And hence you fill a red rectangle which is (600, 5, 400, 400), meaning that the top-left corner of that rectangle is in 600,5 (since you call `g.fillRect(getX(), getY(),...`) which is outside the bounds of the component.

When you use BorderLayout, your component gets the bounds (0,0,1600,900) (minus the borders of the frame) and calling g.fillRect(getX(), getY(),... will work since x,y is (0,0).

Try to call this instead:

```
g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Comment: (slaps forehead)  Right!  I looked at that code several times yet missed it each time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Don't hurt yourself, please. I don't mean any harm to anyone and I would feel bad to post answers in the future :-)

Comment: Don't worry, no SO helper suffered due to the preparation of my messages.  ;)

Comment: OK, I have understood the workings then, but how do I manage to fill only a rectangle from 400, 400 to 800 800 for example? Or better put, how do I make my component only from 400, 400 to 800, 800

Comment: @Daniel, it depends of the LayoutManager you use. You could use a huge empty border (top=400, left=400, bottom=0, right=0) and return a preferred size (400x400). You can also return a preferred size of (800x800) and paint a rectangle (400,400,400,400). This will work with BorderLayout or FlowLayout(alignement LEFT).

Comment: I would like to have multiple squares on screen in a `JPanel` and if I click and drag them then they should move. On the other hand, if I click on the lower-right part of the rectangle and drag then it should resize. Which approach would you use? Maybe `JComponents` are not what I should be targeting here

Comment: @Daniel JComponent is just fine for that. Maybe you will want to look into JLayeredPane as a parent container. You will then have to provide your own implementation of LayoutManager to compute the preferred size and layout the contained components.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you. I have also found another solution: use null for the layout of the containing JPanel and it seems to draw exactly what I want.

Comment: @Daniel using `null` is really not encouraged for all kinds of very good reasons. I really advice you not to do that (yet you are free to choose). Just my 2 cents.